# Filtering 'reports/product_collection' doesn't seem to work properly anymore

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise

I'm trying to add filters to a collection as below.

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addOrderedQty()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')            
        //->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)   // doesn't work here but works in old example in link
        //->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 3)    // doesn't work here but works in old example in link
        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc'); //best sellers on top
```

I got this code from [this old source](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14764/) (2008), but it seems to be no longer working as-is. It seems that the `reports/product_collection` only includes a limited number of fields, which excludes `sku` among many others.

Additionally, even though it includes `status` and `visibility`,  filtering those attributes doesn't seem to work. e.g. this doesn't work (that's why I commented them out) and the collection will return zero products even though the products I want have those values.

```
->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) or ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 3)
```

how can I have it include more fields?

Answer (score 3):

Try like this, this works in Magento 1.7 CE

```
    $visibility = array(
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
    );


    $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addOrderedQty()
                        ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                        ->setVisibility($visibility)                   
                        ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
                        ->setPage(0, 4);
```

The category will be the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category` object.

**Update**

If you want to add a category filter

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
```

I have been using this code in Magento 1.7 CE. Have you tried in array format `array(1,3)`?

Comment: Is this tested? The `setVisibility($visibility)` line does not work for me. I'm using EE 1.12, but don't think it should matter. I've tried single values as well like 1 or 3. Also, how would I set up `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category`?